# How to determine location in browser of non supporting html5 mobile device?

Tags: html, geolocation

I have an html5 web page that displays a specific advert depending on the mobile device's geo/location.

How do you determine the location on a handset that doesn't support html5 (older nokias and blackberrys) from inside the (old) browser?

Comment: You probably don't, period. Unless those devices offer some proprietary, alternative solution.

Comment: I just found this, would this work / help?: http://www.tonybunce.com/2008/05/08/Blackberry-Browser-Amp-GPS.aspx

Comment: Yes, that looks like an alternative, proprietary API, like I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it server side based on the IP address, using libraries such as Geo::IP. It's a lot less accurate (especially in the case of mobile devices), but if the browser won't give you a location there's no way to guess it.

Comment: Server side geolocation is all but useless for mobile devices. You'll probably get the right continent, if you're lucky the right country.

Answer (score 0):

I Am Assuming you can use Javascript in your web page.
You can use geopoition.js fallback technique. There are Device specific solutions are also available.

So you can start with Detecting support for HTML5 (instead of assuming)

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
// let's find out where you are!
} else {
// no native geolocation support available :(
// try geoPosition.js or another third-party solution
}
```

You can include Modernizr library from a cdn resource
    `<script src="modernizr.min.js"></script>`
Now using geoposition you can workaround . 
Here is the Example from github
In head section

```
<script src="js/geoPosition.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Then call it this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(geoPosition.init()){  // Geolocation Initialisation
        geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(success_callback,error_callback,{enableHighAccuracy:true});
}else{
        // You cannot use Geolocation in this device
}
geoPositionSimulator.init(); 

// p : geolocation object
function success_callback(p){
    // p.latitude : latitude value
    // p.longitude : longitude value
}

function error_callback(p){
    // p.message : error message
}
```

You can refer to following resources that may help you

Detecting geolocation  : http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#geolocation
Using Geoposition: github.com/estebanav/javascript-mobile-desktop-geolocation
Specific Resource for Blackberry: tonybunce.com/2008/05/08/Blackberry-Browser-Amp-GPS.aspx

Hope this may help